# List C++ how to edit specific element

Tags: c++, list, pointers

I'm getting a bit confused with lists. See below:

```
int ParticleSystemManager::CreateParticleSystem()
{
    ParticleSystem* system = new ParticleSystem(Vector3(), Vector3(), 10, 1);
    system->SetLifeTime(200);

    list<ParticleSystem>::iterator it = particleSystems.begin();

    particleSystems.insert(it, *system);

    selectedParticleSystem = system;

    return 0;
}
```

What I'm wanting to do is get the particleSystem I've just created add it to the list of Particle Systems, BUT I'm also wanting to store that added particle system in a pointer. I'm noticing though that when the iterating through the list the memory locations are different to the location stored by the selectedParticleSystem pointer. How can I make them the same? The update is below:

```
void ParticleSystemManager::Update(float elapsedTime)
{
    for (std::list<ParticleSystem>::iterator iterator = particleSystems.begin(), end = particleSystems.end(); iterator != end; ++iterator) 
    {
        iterator->Update(elapsedTime);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm noticing though that when the iterating through the list the memory locations are different to the location stored by the selectedParticleSystem pointer.

That's because `std::list::insert` creates a **copy** of the object.

Your options are:

1. Create a `list` of pointers instead (although for several reasons, you may want to use *smart pointers* instead).
2. Obtain a pointer to the object inside the list, and store that instead.  Something like:

   ```
   selectedParticleSystem = &(*particleSystems.insert(it, *system));
   ```

   If you do this, you'll of course need to `delete` the original object, otherwise you'll have a memory leak.

Comment: Thanks, I did the latter option and changed the declaration of the particle system to be declared as a value rather than a pointer.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to the answer by Oli: If you use C++11 you could use [emplace](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/emplace)  instead, to create the new ParticleSystem directy in the list:

```
particleSystems.emplace(particleSystems.begin(),Vector3(), Vector3(), 10, 1);
particleSystems.begin()->SetLifeTime(200);

selectedParticleSystem=particleSystems.begin();
```